# NullPointerException при работе с файлами

Tags: java

выдаёт NullPointerException при работе с файлами, и не работает, помогите разобраться. Создаю переменную *file* куда записывается файл выбранный пользователем в одном классе,

```
File file;
    public File getFile() {
        return file;
    }
if (cmd.equals("Quelldatei auswählen")) {
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            fileChooser
                    .setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
            int ret = fileChooser.showDialog(this, "auswählen");
            if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                file= fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsoluteFile();
                contentPane.add(new JLabel("Quelldatei ist: " + file));
```

и вызываю его из метода др. класса соотв. создав объект этого класса вызываю этот файл через *gd.getFile()*

```
GUIDialog gd;
public void doit() {
    try {
        gd=new GUIDialog();
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(gd.getFile()));
```

но при нажатии на кнопку кот. должна брать этот переданный файл и преобразовывать, выпадает  NullPointerException указывая на эту строчку *in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(gd.getFile()));*, что делается здесь неправильно, помогите советами.

Comment: Так а где путь к файлу то? Где объект самого файла? У вас ссылка, которая никуда не ссылается. Должно быть что то типа File file = new File("/var/www/file.txt");

Comment: есть UI где нажатием на кнопку "Quelldatei auswählen" выбирается файл, и надо чтоб при нажатии кнопку "Auslesen" вызывался класс c методом doit() к переменной которого  "in" будет указываться этот выбранный пользователем файл в др. классе. Выбирается файл пользователем в переменную patch File patch = fileChooser.getSelectedFile(); т.е это не определенный файл, а может быть любым

Comment: Когда вы вызываете getFile(), то переменная file просто не инициализируется, потому и выкидывает NPE. Поместите код сравнения прямо в конструктор класса, и выкидывать перестанет. По крайней мере, этот надоедливый NullPointerException :)

Comment: @Vulpes, тогда вы просто можете вынести сравнение в отдельный метод, а в конструкторе например сделать так:


`public File getFile() {
sravnenie();
return file;
}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> тогда вы просто можете вынести сравнение в отдельный метод, а в конструкторе например сделать так:
>
> ```
> public File getFile() { sravnenie(); return file; }
> ```

спасибо большое работает, но только уже через нажатие на 1 кнопку :)